# Как верстать статьи в joomla?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, joomla, адаптивная-верстка

Как верстать в джумле? Например мне нужно сделать статью, в которой будет row с двумя span6. Стили я могу сохранять в css файле текущей темы. А в каком файле мне нужно сохранять html статьи, создавать row и спаны?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: mr_blond97, Вот [сюда](http://q-seo.ru/articles/joomla-lesson/dobavit-statju-v-joomla-3) вам!

Comment: Мне непонятно было как именно делать html разметку в этом cms. Выяснилось, что это делается в редакторе статьи в "добавить код".